# R: How to drop rows that contain any value less than -4 and greater than 4 on specific columns?

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
A  B  C
1  8  2
3  3  -9
2  3  3
1  1  1
```

I want to drop the first two rows since they contain values less than -4 and greater than 4. My code is not working for me:

```
df[which((df[,c(B,C)]>-4 & df[,c(B,C)] < 4),)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can use `rowSums` to select rows where there are no values less than  -4 or greater than 4.

```
cols <- c('B', 'C')
df[rowSums(df[cols] < -4 | df[cols] > 4, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]

#  A B C
#3 2 3 3
#4 1 1 1
```

Also with `apply` :

```
df[apply(df[cols] > -4 & df[cols] < 4, 1, all), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), B = c(8L, 3L, 3L, 1L), 
    C = c(2L, -9L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```